# How can I copy values from one Tensorflow variable to another?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm experimenting with Keras using the Tensorflow backend and am trying to better understand how tensor variables work. I've modified the update function of Keras' Stochastic Gradient Descent to see if I can copy values from one variable to another.

At the moment, I can't, but have no idea why.

I've modified the `get_updates` method of the SGD class to create a copy of the `params` variable, which stores the weights and biases of the net. I update this copy in the same way as the original. When I update the original using the updated values of the copy, no values appear to update. When I update the original using updated values of the original, the update is effective. I have no idea why one case works and the other does not.

Below is the modified version of the `get_updates` method. I allow for both the regular(reasonable) way to update the params variable and shown how I update using the copy.

```
@interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
def get_updates(self, loss, params):
    # Copy parameters - Create copy of net parameters
    params_tmp = []
    for p in params:
        params_tmp.append(K.variable(K.get_value(p), name=p.name[:-2] + "_cpy/"))

    self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]
    self.weights = [self.iterations]

    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)  # Get Initial Gradient
                                              # for Heun
    for p, p_tmp, g in zip(params, params_tmp, grads):
        v = - self.lr * g
        new_p = p + v
        new_p_tmp = p_tmp + v   # Getting intermediate update
                                # using first gradient from Heun

        # Apply constraints.
        if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
            new_p = p.constraint(new_p)
        if getattr(p_tmp, 'constraint', None) is not None:
            new_p_tmp = p_tmp.constraint(new_p_tmp)

        # Copy completed Heun update back to original param
        self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p_tmp))  # Doesnt Work
        #self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))     # Works

    return self.updates
```

For Tensorflow, Keras, update function is

```
def update(x, new_x):
    """Update the value of `x` to `new_x`.

    # Arguments
        x: A `Variable`.
        new_x: A tensor of same shape as `x`.

    # Returns
        The variable `x` updated.
    """
    return tf.assign(x, new_x)
```

Why can't I update the params variable using updated values of the copy?